# How to obtain the unsampled samples after PROC SURVEYSELECT in SAS?

Tags: sas, sample, proc, random, sample-data

I use `PROC SURVEYSELECT` in SAS to sample a data set `DT`, `OUT=DT_SAMPLED`, but I would also like to have those samples in `DT` that didn't get selected. May I know if there is a way? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `OUTALL` statement on `PROC SURVEYSELECT`, which will output all records with a `selected` flag for selected records.

```
proc surveyselect data=sashelp.class outall out=classsamp n=5 seed=7;
run;

proc freq data=classsamp;
tables selected;
run;
```

You will see 5 selected (1) and 14 unselected (0).